# PHP variable doesn't echo in table when function called

Tags: php, function, scope

I have a simple Vars.php page:

```
<?php
//Vars.php
$WeekOfDateSelected = date('l, m/d/Y', strtotime($MonthYear));
$NextSundayOfDateSelected = date('l, m/d/Y', strtotime('this Sunday', strtotime($WeekOfDateSelected)));

?>
```

I have another PHP that includes Vars.php and builds a table:

```
<html>
<?php
//AnalyticsTest.php

include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/~/~/~/~/~/Vars.php");

function WeekTable() {

echo "<table id=\"a\">
<tr>
<th style=\"text-align: center;\"><a href=\"#\">< previous week</a></th>
<th colspan=\"4\" style=\"text-align: center;\"><h2>Week of ";
echo $WeekOfDateSelected;
echo " - "; 
echo $NextSundayOfDateSelected; 
echo "</th>
<th style=\"text-align: center;\"><a href=\"#\">next week ></a></th>
</tr>
</table>";

}

?>

</html>
```

Basically, when I call `WeekTable()` everything outputs correctly except for the PHP variables `$WeekOfDateSelected` and `$NextSundayOfDateSelected`, which output blank.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to pass those variables as parameters to that function. Otherwise they are [out of scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

```
function WeekTable($WeekOfDateSelected,$NextSundayOfDateSelected) {
    // ...
}
```

Make sure you pass them when you call the function:

```
 WeekTable($WeekOfDateSelected,$NextSundayOfDateSelected);
```

You can also use the `global` keyword but that is a bad programming practice so I will not show that here.

Comment: I'm getting a "Missing argument 1 for WeekTable()" and "Missing argument 2 for WeekTable()" error ... I'm in Wordpress as well (not sure if that impacts anything)

Comment: You don't have the variables in your function call. It should look like this: `WeekTable($WeekOfDateSelected,$NextSundayOfDateSelected);`